# how to redirect from vue router-link using query?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router, query-string, routerlink

How to add a query to the router-link so the user will be redirected to the comment under a post by clicking on the link from the notification?

API gives us an `anchor` of the notification and `id` of the comment. When the DOM renders a page, it loads a post firstly, then comments.

Here is a component of the notification:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <span>
   <i class="g-font-size-18 g-color-gray-light-v1"></i>
    </span>
     <router-link :to="linkFromNotification(item)
                  @click.native="linkFromNotification(item.notification_type)">
    <p>
     <span v-html="item.message"></span>
    </p>
  </router-link>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'


 export default {
 props: ['item'],
 computed: {
 ...mapGetters([
 'getNotifications'
  ])
 },
 methods: {
 ...mapActions([
 'readNotification'
 ]),
 linkFromNotification (item) {
    if (item.notification_type === 'user_subscribed') {
      return {name: 'person', params: {id: item.object_id}}
    } else if (['comment_created', 'answer_selected', 'answer_created'].includes(item.notification_type)) {
      return {name: 'show_post', params: {id: item.object_id}}
    } else if (item.notification_type === 'user_coauthored') {
      return {name: 'show_post', params: {id: item.object_id}}
     }
    }
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean url queries you can use key query in the object you are returning,
If you mean a hash "#" to be added to the link you can use the key hash. for example:

```
{name: 'person', params: {id: item.object_id}, query:{name:"Mohd"}, hash:"214"}
```

[Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html)

Comment: What exactly did you pass in the query's name?

Comment: If we need to be addressed to the comment under the post (see the second condition and return in `linkFromNotification`, does it mean that we can pass into the query `comment.id`?

Comment: you can pass query like `return {name: 'show_post', params: {id: item.object_id} , query: { comment_id: comment.id }}` if that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, I meant this. So after I added the query, how the rendered page will scroll down to the very comment?

Comment: for scrolling you need to use [Scroll Behavior method](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) , check out the last code before Async Scrolling section